# Estimation in STAN - help modelling a multinomial

Tags: multinomial-distribution, stan

I have data like the following:

```
    a   b   c
   --- --- ---
    0   1   6     <- replicate 1, trial 1
    1   1   5
    0   0   7
    0   1   6
    0   0   7
    1   5   10     <- replicate 2, trial 1
    0   4   12
    0   5   11
    2   4   10
    2   3   11
    2   5   9   ...
```

where each row is an observation modelled as a multinomial (really categorical) with a vector valued parameter $\theta$ representing proportions (in a, b or c) summing to 1. The problem is that I have data from multiple biological replicates, where each replicate had a different total number of subjects (eg. 7 in rows 1-5 and 16 in rows 10-11). Each replicate involved 5-10 repeated trials, and observations from each trial are recorded as a row in the table above. I am modelling each row as iid multinomial.

If I do something like the following in STAN:

```
data {
    int y[num_rows, num_cols];
 }
parameters {
    simplex[num_cols] theta;
}
model {
    for (i in 1:num_rows) {
        y[i,] ~ multinomial(theta);
    } 
    // some prior on theta
}
```

it doesn't complain. I am just wondering whether this is the right thing to do because I'm not sure what STAN is doing under the hood, considering that the multinomial specification does not require a fixed int parameter (but only a vector of probabilities), but the binomial does. Should I be estimating parameters separately for the different replicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing the right thing.

According to the Stan User Manual, the multinomial distribution figures out what N, the total count, is by calculating the sum of y. In your case, it will know that there were 7 subjects in the first row by calculating 0 + 1 + 6.

Stan can't do this for the binomial distribution, since the data there is just the number of successes and not the number of successes and the number of failures (from which it would have been able to calculate N).

If you expect the same parameter $\theta$ to govern all of your replicates, then you should just estimate a single $\theta$, the way you are doing now. If for some reason you think that the different replicates will have different probability vectors governing them, you should estimate separate $\theta$s.

Comment: Yup, came to the same conclusion after some thinking. Thanks for the confirmation. Cheers.